# How does this code sample from a spherical map?

Tags: glsl, trigonometry

Going through this tutorial from:
https://learnopengl.com/PBR/IBL/Diffuse-irradiance

I encountered this piece of code:

```
const vec2 invAtan = vec2(0.1591, 0.3183);
vec2 SampleSphericalMap(vec3 direction)
{
    vec2 uv = vec2(atan(direction.z, direction.x), asin(direction.y));
    uv *= invAtan;
    uv += 0.5;
    return uv;
}
```

To sample a image that looks like this:
[image]

My question is where does this come from as well as the magic "invAtan" constant?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The image you posted is an [equirectangular projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equirectangular_projection) of a 360 degree photograph taken next to the [Colosseum in Rome, Italy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colosseum).

The `invAtan` constant is the [reciprocal(or multiplicative inverse)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_inverse) of `2PI` and `PI`:

`0.1591` = `1/6.28319`(=>`2PI`) = 360 degrees in radians

`0.3183` = `1/3.14159`(=>`PI`) = 180 degrees in radians

So you go from [cartesian coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system) to [polar angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system) to uvs, see [this great resource(headline: Direct Polar)](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/transformationprojection/). In more practical terms, assuming that given `direction` is normalized(hence mapped to the [unit-sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_sphere)) multiplying by `invAtan` transformes the values into the `[-.5,.5]` range, adding `.5` results in uv lookup coordinates in the range of `[0,1]`.

Comment: Thanks, also my question wasn't regarding the picture I knew what it was. I was asking about the code.

Comment: Oh.. well, I assume the author of the tutorial wrote it, its a fairly common thing to write.